# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: java, spring-mvc, oracle12c, ora-01017

I have an issue regarding connecting a spring project to an oracle database 12 c.

My config.properties file is like the following

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521:sid
jdbc.username=XXXX
jdbc.password=XXXX
```

My aplication-context.xml file is as follows:

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
   </bean>
```

This was working before, but then we changed the username of the database for something else and then it stopped working.

Previously we had a problem with the encoding and since our password has an underscore in it, we had to used a escape character to make it work like this (`\`). But then again we had to change the username and it stopped working!

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"we changed the username"* and then began getting "invalid username/password" error? And you're surprised?!? Did you change the `config.properties` to the new username? And give the correct password for that new user?

Comment: of course I've changed the password and username on the config.properties. But something is wrong with the underscores "_" . I have created a new user and remove that character from the password and it works!  i don't know why I can't have "_" in my username or password...

Answer (score 1):

**1) Try jdbc URL on this format:**

jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521:oracle

**2) Try Driver class:**
      oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

```
    Because class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver extends oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.
```

---

Test one by one Or both.. I hope it works.

---

Comment: Rises other exception **Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory**. I have created other user without the "_" (underscores) and granted all privileges to this new user to my user with the underscores (sch_user). And it's working but it's still very strange... Thank you for your time :)